# 'FeedItem' schema type undefined in Trigger

Tags: chatter, dynamic-dml

I am trying to dynamically create an sObject in APEX based on the following code.

```
Schema.SObjectType targetType = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('FeedItem'); 
system.debug(targetType);
sObject chatterUpdate = targetType.newSObject();
chatterUpdate.put('ParentId', '00QU000000ARlWG');
chatterUpdate.put('Body','New update!');
insert chatterUpdate;
```

Where the `ParentId` is from a Lead Record.

In the *execute anonymous environment* the code executes fine, and the chatter update is created. The `Schema.SObjectTpe targetType` is defined (with Chatter enabled obviously) but in the context of an `AfterUpdate` trigger on a custom sObject...the `TargetType` is `null`???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is kind of a wild guess but is the api version of the trigger or trigger handler fairly old?

I believe that feeditems only came out in 23 so a globaldescribe with an older api version will return null.

Comment: Hmmm good thought let me try updating the API version of the class...

Comment: We have a winner. Updating the API Version fixed this. I figured the `globaldescribe` wouldn't be limited to objects that weren't available prior to a specific API version. Is that documented?

Comment: I doubt that this is explicitly documented for `globaldescribe` but the system methods are generally versioned so that new releases don't break existing code. Just like `describeGlobal()` for an old version of web services api will not return feedItems.

Comment: Sure though I would argue this isn't a `backwards compatibility` issue, it's like a `non-forward compatibility issue`, this feature _exists_ in your "org" but _doesn't exist to this code_ ... I'm not certified or anything so I guess I didn't do my homework ON THE DOCUMENTATION (:

Comment: I'd expect global describe to work this way - what's the sense in returning tokens for SObjectTypes that your API version isn't capable of working with?